# Problem with loading updated data from Firestore in a Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I have one Fragment that updates a field in Firestore and then after the update the next Fragment gets opened. There the updated data should be displayed in two TextViews but currently the method I used to retrieve the date from Firestore is loading the old data, not the from the previous Fragment updated data.

It seems that the new Fragment gets opened too fast so it still reads the old data from Firestore, how can I achieve that it retrieves the updated data?

I already tried to call the method in Fragment 2 in the `onViewCreated` and `onStart` method but also there it gets the old data:

Here is my first Fragment that updates the fields in Firestore before opening the next Fragment: ( I call the method below in the `onClick`method)

```
...

gamesRef.document(gameId).update(currentUserUid, pointsPlayer1Str)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                ((GameActivity) getActivity()).setViewPager(7);
                                            }
                                        });

...
```

The I try to retrieve the updated data in the second Fragment, in the `onCreateView`:

```
...
gameRef.document(gameId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null) {
                        pointsPlayer1Str = document.getString(currentUserUid);
                        pointsPlayer2Str = document.getString(uidPlayer2);

                        textViewPointsCurrentUser.setText(pointsPlayer1Str);
                        textViewPointsOpponent.setText(pointsPlayer2Str);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
...
```

Where should I call the method from the second fragment to get the updated data?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your view pager configs?

Comment: Alternatively, you can just attach a real-time listener to your data with `addSnapshotListener`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: @Christilyn Thank you for the tipp, that worked for me. When you post it as answer I can accept it

Comment: Glad I could help. I've edited my post for the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a real-time listener to your data instead with the following:

```
val docRef = gameRef.document(gameId)
docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
        return@addSnapshotListener
    }

    if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: ${snapshot.data}")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null")
    }
}
```